# C# oledb Number of query values and destination fields are not the same

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I'm receiving the error of "Number of query values and destination fields are not the same." for the part of code which appears below -

```
        public static void SaveCurrentPlaylistToSheet(YouTubeVideo[] CurrentPlaylist)
    {
        string currentTitle;

        using (connection = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;

            using (command = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < CurrentPlaylist.Length; i++) 
                {
                    currentTitle = Regex.Replace(CurrentPlaylist[i].title, " ", "");

                    if (NewPlaylist)
                    {
                        command.CommandText = string.Format("INSERT INTO [" + ActiveSheetTitle + "] (F1) values({0})", currentTitle);
                        NewPlaylist = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        command.CommandText = string.Format("INSERT INTO [" + ActiveSheetTitle + "$] (F1) values({0})", currentTitle);
                    }
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery(); // Execute insert query against excel file.
                }
            }
```

any help for solving the issue will be appreciated.
Thanks,
Amitai

Comment: What if your currentTitle variable contains a comma? Concatenating strings to form sql commands is bad, really bad. Use parameters

Comment: Also, you would need to wrap the string with single quotes for the query engine to understand it.

Comment: My first thought is the same as the others, there's a good chance you have a string sanitation issue with the playlists.  Have you tried catching the exception in the debugger and then inspecting the command text to see if this is your issue?

Answer (score 1):

If your currentTitle variable happens to have a comma then your query fails because it is considered as two fields. You should use parameters when you build your query text and pass the value using the parameters collection

```
string cmdText = "INSERT INTO [" + ActiveSheetTitle + "] (F1) values(?)";
if (NewPlaylist)
    NewPlaylist = false;
command.Parameters.Add("@f1", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = currentTitle;
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

A point to consider is also the ActiveSheetTitle variable. Do not let your user type that value. You should have it defined somewhere from a whitelist of names to avoid possible Sql Injections on that variable.